# JSX extra white space when using Split Map

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

How do I remove this white space? As you can see from my code, "Description" should be on its own line, and the text should go below it. **This issue only occurs for some strings from the database**, but AFAIK the strings from the database are all essentially the same - different messages but the same exact format.

Also, if I displayed only `{this.state.info}` inside the `<Text>` component, the layout is as expected. **It only breaks with the split and map functions.**

[image]

Expected outcome:

[image]

I am trying to split a text, `this.state.info` in JS React. The text contains "||" delimiter which indicates a new line break.

For example, "this||text" should really be: 
"this 
text"

Here is my code. It splits on '||' and puts each segment in paragraphs and then also replaces the string `<p>` in the text, if there are any, with empty strings.

```
            <Text fontStyle={TEXT_STYLE.BOLD}>Description</Text>
            <div
              className="textMinimumHeight"
              style={{minHeight: "111px"}}>
              <Text>
                {this.state.info.split('||').map((item, i) => {
                  return <p key={i}>{item.replace('<p>', '')}</p>;})
                }
              </Text>
            </div>
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: i think it would be useful to also replace the closing `p` tags : `.replace('</p>', '')`

Comment: @Taki thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately the issue is still there :(

Comment: Can you show us the markup this is producing? It sounds like the part with the split text is being treated as something like `display: inline-block` and it is going to the next line below the header when any of the text lines is long enough. You should inspect the elements with the text and any containing them in your browser tools to see if there is an inline-block style being applied somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do this:

```
1. <Text fontStyle={TEXT_STYLE.BOLD}>{`Description\n`}</Text>

2. <Text fontStyle={TEXT_STYLE.BOLD}>Description{`\n`}</Text>

or just put description inside <p> tag

3. <Text fontStyle={TEXT_STYLE.BOLD}><p>Description</p></Text>
```

Comment: It turned out that the issue was with my direct parent tag, a container component that malfunctioned when there are more than 1 child. I put the "Description" outside of the parent component and the issue was fixed. Your suggestion helped to troubleshoot, thanks!